# How to express a change in odds ratio

Tags: probability, odds-ratio, odds

I recently encountered a problem at work. It concerned the change in odds of getting into higher education depending on socio-economic background over time.

At time one ($T_1$) the odds of getting into higher education for those in the bottom socio-economic tier compared to the top tier was $\frac{1}{3.7}$ - so for every 1 person in the bottom tier 3.7 get in at the top. At $T_2$ the odds where $\frac{1}{2.4}$. Someone writing a report on this said it meant likelihood of getting into the higher education for people in the lowest socio-economic tier were 65% higher at $T_2$ than at $T_1$. I'm pretty sure that this is at best misleading.

I tried to convert the odds to probabilities by taking  $P = \frac{O}{O + 1}$: for $T_1$, $0.79 = \frac{3.7}{3.7+1}$. Then I subtracted this from 1 to give the probability for the lowest socio-economic tier at the two time points: $T_1=0.21, T_2=0.29$.

Now I want to indicate change. Do I say that the probability has increased by .08 or 8% or do I create a ratio of probabilities ($T_2$ is 38% larger than $T_1$)?

Finally, I'm worried that I'm way of the mark, as the initial figures are odds ratios (between the two socio-economic tiers) rather than odds, and therefore I'm not calculating probabilities correctly.

Can anyone explain the best way describe the change in the two time points in a language that will not confuse laymen?